# AWK Command Argument Error

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, arguments

I have a dataset which contains contact information of students, the sample data set is as follows

```
First Name, Last Name, Address, Phone Number
John, Doe, "House # 11, Street xyz, Road, Area",00000000
Sara, Taylor, "Jake Lake%, Apartment #22, Main Road, Area XYZ", 00000000
```

I am running the following command to replace **,** inside Address column to **|** to load it into the DB.

```
awk '!(NR%2){gsub(",","|")} {printf RFS $0} {RFS="\""}' RS=\" fileName.txt > output.txt
```

The issue I am facing is the whenever I ran this command it returns me the following error, Initially it was running ok

```
awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf(""Jake Lake%, Apartment #22, Main Road, Area XYZ")
```

Is there any solution to that? I noticed that **%** is coming in the address is that the issue?

Comment: Why do you use `printf`? You need a format string for that to work, which you didn't provide ... did you mean to just use `print`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. For robustness, never do `printf $0`, always use `printf "%s", $0` instead as the former will fail when your input contains `printf` formatting characters (as you are currently seeing). The same applies to using `printf` with any input data.
2. For clarity and robustness, never use all-upper-case variable names, e.g. `RFS` to avoid clashes with builtin variable names and to avoid obfuscating your code by making it look like you're using a built-in variable when you aren't.
3. For readability, don't set variables, e.g. `RS`, after your script unless you need to set them to different values for different input files, set variables before or at the start of your script so when reading your script we see them being set before we see them being used.
4. For efficiency, simplicity, robustness, the first argument to *sub() is a regexp, not a string, so use regexp (`/.../`), not string (`"..."`) delimiters around it unless you NEED a dynamic instead of static regexp for some reason.
5. For clarity and maintainability, when you have 2 variables that must have the same value, e.g. `RS` and `RFS`, don't set them separately to the same value, e.g. `RS="\""; RFS="\""`, either set them together to that value, e.g. `RS=RFS="\""` or set one to the other, e.g. `RS="\""; RFS=RS`.

This is how to write the code in your question correctly:

```
$ awk -v RS='"' '!(NR%2){gsub(/,/,"|")} {printf "%s%s", rfs, $0; rfs=RS}' file
First Name, Last Name, Address, Phone Number
John, Doe, "House # 11| Street xyz| Road| Area",00000000
Sara, Taylor, "Jake Lake%| Apartment #22| Main Road| Area XYZ", 00000000
```

To do any more than that with a CSV using awk, see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 2):

The error that you get is due to using the concatenation of the value of `RFS` (an empty variable) and `$0` as the format string with `printf`.

Your file is a valid CSV file, apart from having spaces after some of the delimiting commas (which messes up the quoting of the `Address` field; a quoted field needs to have the initial quote character directly after the delimiter).  We may correct this using `csvformat` (part of csvkit from https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bsh
$ csvformat --skipinitialspace file.csv >fixed-file.csv
$ cat fixed-file.csv
First Name,Last Name,Address,Phone Number
John,Doe,"House # 11, Street xyz, Road, Area",00000000
Sara,Taylor,"Jake Lake%, Apartment #22, Main Road, Area XYZ",00000000
```

A database that can parse CSV should be able to read this as it is.

Would you still want to replace all embedded commas into `|`, simply change the file's delimiter to something other than a comma (I'll use tabs below), change all the remaining commas into pipes, and change back to using commas as delimiters again.

We can do this on the original data directly:

```bsh
$ csvformat --skipinitialspace --out-tabs file.csv | tr ',' '|' | csvformat --tabs >fixed-file.csv
$ cat fixed-file.csv
First Name,Last Name,Address,Phone Number
John,Doe,House # 11| Street xyz| Road| Area,00000000
Sara,Taylor,Jake Lake%| Apartment #22| Main Road| Area XYZ,00000000
```

The short variants of the various long options used are `-S` for `--skipinitialspace`, `-T` for `--out-tabs`, and `-t` for `--tabs`.